# access 2016 calculated fields round to zero

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to include a simple density calculation in access 2016, but the form returns a value of 0 if the input dimensions (mass or sphere diameter) are < 0.5.  The field works fine for larger dimensions, so I assume that the smaller values are getting rounded to 0 somewhere along the way, but I can't figure out where.

For the inputs in my table, I have Field Names "green mass", "green pole", and "green equator" where the data type for each is set to "number," the Field Size is set to "single" (vs. double or decimal), and the Decimal Places is set to 4 digits

The resulting density is displayed in the Field "apparent green density" where the data type is set to "calculated," the Result Type is set to "single" and the Decimal Places is set to 4 digits.

After looking at various access forums and websites, I'm pretty sure I want to use single or double as my field size, but I've also tried decimal and byte and integer I keep getting 0.

Can anyone explain why this isn't working?

The equation is below.  It's a bit complicated because it's a 3-part If statement (if dimensions for a sphere are given, caclulate density of a sphere, if dimensions of a disc are give, calculate density of a disc, if dimensions of a cube...)  All three cases work for large dimensions (>0.5), but all 3 result in 0 for dimensions <0.5.

`IIf([GreenPole],[GreenMass]/(3.14159265359/6*2.54^3*(([GreenPole]+[GreenEquator])/2)^3),IIf([GreenDia],([GreenMass]/(3.14159265359*([GreenDia]/2)^2*[GreenHeight]*2.54^3)),IIf([GreenLength],[GreenMass]/([GreenLength]*[GreenWidth]*[GreenThickness]*2.54^3),0)))`

The first part of the equation for density of a sphere, is:

```
`IIf([GreenPole],[GreenMass]/(3.14159265359/6*2.54^3*(([GreenPole]+[GreenEquator])/2)^3),0)
```

Comment: Difficult to say without knowing the formula used in your calculation.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the formula.  Because I have the same error with all 3 cases (sphere, disc, cube), I'm even more convinced that this is a rounding/ decimal limit somewhere in the table settings...

Comment: Could it be a formatting issue?

Comment: You are doing this in a table Calculated field? Does this happen if calc is in query or textbox?

Comment: I just setup your exact environment and I am not having this issue. My test table has Number (Double) data types for all of the fields involved. I used tiny numbers (like .00823) without issue. Is it possible there are more than 3 IF conditions, and you are getting to the zero? Test this by using this and checking for 999 as your result: 



=IIf(1<>1,[GreenMass]/(3.14159265359/6*2.54^3*(([GreenPole]+[GreenEquator])/2)^3),IIf(1<>1,([GreenMass]/(3.14159265359*([GreenDia]/2)^2*[GreenHeight]*2.54^3)),IIf(1<>1,[GreenMass]/([GreenLength]*[GreenWidth]*[GreenThickness]*2.54^3),999)))

Comment: PS. It looks like [GreenPole], [GreenDia], and [GreenLength] should be Yes/No columns. Your IIF on column 1 will always be true since it does not use boolean logic..In other words, you are always running condition 1 (GreenPole).

Answer (score 0):

Oliver Jacot-Descombes got me started in the right direction.  I don't have much experience at all with coding, but I think what happened is that field identified in my IIf statement is somehow transformed into a boolean or yes/ no field and anything less than 0.5 is rounded to a no and the result of the truepart is then 0.

I modified the code to:

```
IIf([GreenPole]>0,[GreenMass]/(3.14159265359/6*2.54^3*(([GreenPole]+[GreenEquator])/2)^3),0)
```

And everything works now.  (I also modified the second and third IIf statments to `IIf([GreenLength]>0` and `IIF([GreenDia]>0`..)